# Почему liquebase стоит на паузе?

Tags: база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему стоит на паузе? Как его запустить?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «править», расположенную под метками вопроса.